# Saving child entity via WCF using EntityFramework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, parent-child

Say I have a Person and an Address object where a Person has a list of Address objects.  The info is exposed via WCF services, and I'm trying to use EntityFramework 4.1.

If I want to update an Address object on a Person, I want to have a WCF method called UpdateAddress(Address addr).

The DBContext only seems to have a list of Person of which there is a list of Address in the Person object.  Is that the only way to update an Address as it seems that implies it needs to load all of the Person to find an Address to update before saving making it inefficient.

Is there a way to just update without loading the parent entity?

Comment: The Address object should have a PersonId property, doesn't it?

Comment: Than if you only want to update an specific Address object, you shoud pass only it to the WCF, and remember to set it's PersonId property accordingly

Comment: How do I do that using EntityFramework though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Person` is part of the model and `Person` has a collection of `Address` then also `Address` (as a related entity) is part of the model (unless you excluded the Address collection explicitely from the model). That means you can simply add the Address set to the DbContext as a helper property:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

For `UpdateAdress` you can then use:

```
public void UpdateAddress(Address addr)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var addressInDb = context.Addresses.Find(addr.Id);
        context.Entry(addressInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(addr);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Even if you don't want or can't add an `Addresses` DbSet to the context you can use the `Set<T>()` method of the context (as long as T is a model entity - and `Address` should be one):

```
public void UpdateAddress(Address addr)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var addressInDb = context.Set<Address>().Find(addr.Id);
        context.Entry(addressInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(addr);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!  I'm doing code first and typing out my own DbContext didn't know I could just add another DbSet property for Addresses.  Good tip also on using Set<T> -- thanks again!